# smallest to biggest number Difference - Java Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help with Arrays I'm trying to create a simple program that would get the smallest number's difference from the largest number on an Array but it seems like the loop I'm doing does not do what the objective is. example: int [] numbers = {2,5,7,32}... the output has to be "30" since 2 is the smallest and 32 is the biggest number and their difference is "30". here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] value   = {5,16,3,32};

    int diff = 0;
    int highest = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i<value.length; i++)
   {
       for(int y = 0;y<value.length;y++)
       {            
           diff = value[i] - value[y];

           if(diff > highest){
               highest = diff;

               System.out.println("the difference of the lowest and the highest is "+ diff);
           }    
       }  
   }
```

} 
}

please help, I'm still learning tricks and stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: You can do this with only one loop, see my answer.

Comment: Hi, you can do this in one line without loops, please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to record both the minimum and maximum, *and then* compute the difference; what is more, only a single loop is needed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] value   = {5,16,3,32};
    // Guarantee sane initial min/max
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


    for (final int val: value) {
        if (val < min)
            min = val;
        if (val > max)
            max = val;
    }

    System.out.println("diff is " + (max - min));
}
```

The "trick" here (if this can be called a trick) is of course the initial values of `min` and `max`.

NOTE: there is a risk of overflow here. Left as an exercise as to how to avoid it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and note the following:

1. You'll want to print the max difference only at the end of the 'for' loops. That way, you'll only print the max.
2. You can perform fewer comparisons if you just look at the absolute value of the difference and only examine each pair of elements once (note the 'j = i+1' and 'Math.abs(...)' lines).
3. I changed 'y' to 'j' as 'i/j' is more idiomatic in Java.

Here's the code:

```
   int[] value   = {5,16,3,32,6};

   int diff = 0;
   int highest = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
   {
       for(int j = i+1; j < value.length; j++)
       {            
           diff = Math.abs(value[i] - value[j]);

           if (diff > highest) {
               highest = diff;
           }    
       }  
   }
   System.out.println("the difference of the lowest and the highest is "+ highest);
```

Comment: That is two loops where only one is needed, though.

Comment: Sure, you could just traverse the array and track the min and max elements. That would work as well. But this solution mirrors the OP's intuition of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use lambdaj ([website](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) - [download](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4.jar)), this library is very powerfull for managing collections, the following code is very simple and works perfectly:

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] values   = {5,16,2,32};

        int minValue = min(values, on(Integer.class));
        int maxValue = max(values, on(Integer.class));
        System.out.print("Rtn:" + (maxValue - minValue)); //Print 30
    }

}
```

With this library you can solve your problem in one line. You must add to your project lambdaj-2.4.jar Hope this help serve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two loops since you are only traversing a 1 dimensional array. Also, if you place the `println` statement inside the loop it will print multiple times, is that what you want? if not place it at the end. Try the following:

```
int min=value[0];
int max=value[0];
int diff=0;

for(int i=0; i < value.length; i++)
{
    if(value[i]<min)
        min=value[i];
    if(value[i]>max)
        max=value[i];
}
diff = max-min;
System.out.println("The difference of the lowest and the highest is "+diff);
```

Comment: As none of the values in the array are less than zero, `min` will never be assigned a value.  At the end of the loop, `min` is still `0`, and `max` is `32`, so the difference calculated in your code is `32`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Bartek Actually, it will *only* work accurately if the array contains non-positive values.

Comment: @Bartek , you are right, I edited the code to work correctly now.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using double for loops so I could get the lowest and highest which is now I understand is wrong. Thank you kind sir :D

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following. we can do it in o(n);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] value   = {5,16,3,32};
 int lowest = 2147483647;
 int highest = 0;
 int diff = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i<value.length; i++)
 {
   if(value[i] < lowest){
     lowest = value[i];
   }
   if(value[i] > highest){
     highest = value[i];
   }
  } 
  diff = highest-lowest;
  system.out.println("The difference is "+ diff);
}
```

Comment: If the array has only negative values, this will output incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this if array is not sorted already:

1. Find the smallest and largest number from the array.
2. Subtract the smallest from largest.

If array is sorted:

1. Subtract 0 index from array.length-1

Answer (score 0):

```
//find the difference between shortest no and largest no//
import java.util.*;
class main15
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the no of elements");
        int no=sc.nextInt();
        int i;
        int a[]=new int[no];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int x=a[0];
        int y=a[a.length-1];
        System.out.println("Difference is="+(y-x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have the array easily sorted with `Arrays.sort`. Then the first element is the smallest and the last the largest:

```
int[] value= {5,16,3,32,6};
Arrays.sort(value);
int min = value[0];
int max = value[value.length-1];
int dif = max-min;
```

Comment: not computationally efficient
its O(n log n), most efficent is O(n). Unless random-select algorithm is used, then it might work in O(1).

Comment: @Bartek Less efficient, but by far the simplest, easiest to understand and maintain. So it would be the best choice if you knew that you are dealing with a relatively small table.